# Socketio (React & Flask app) works on localhost but not when deployed on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, flask, heroku, socket.io

server:

```py
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, port=5000)
```

client:

```
socket = io("http://www.foobar.net:5000");
```

The system works properly when on localhost, but when I deploy it to Heroku, it does not work. In the logs I can see that the server-side `@socketio.on("connect")` fires, and emits the client-side event...

```js
socket.on("current_player", (data) => {
  setCurrentPlayer(data.currentPlayer); 
  console.log("test")
});
```

...which fires because it logs `test`, but it does not pass any data, setCurrentPlayer does not change.

I get errors like these in the browser console:

```
POST http://www.foobar.net/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OYrxuha&sid=7Un1ruUPfZIQqPPtAAAy 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```